# Why does the content height of my <iframe> keep increasing?

Tags: jquery

Here are the functions calling it:

```
$("#iFrame").load(function () { resizeIframe(); }); // on load resize is called
loadIFrame(url); //this loads url in i frame 



function resizeIframe() {
    var iFHeight = $('iFrame').contents().height();
    var iFWidth = $('iFrame').contents().width();

    $("#content").css("height", iFHeight);
    $("#content").css("width", iFWidth);
}
```

If first time on load of iFrame height of content is 100px, second time on load of iFrame height of content is 200px. Third time on load height of content is again 100px, but it is stuck at 200px. Why is not changing the heights? Even though height is now 100px?

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the problem in http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Include the HTML for the `#content` element as well as the code that calls that function.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have diffrent content inside your iframe, or the contenxt haven't loaded completly the first time.

Comment: When do you call `resizeIframe`?

Comment: I added how i am calling the method.

Comment: Is `iFrame` the `id` of `iframe`?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli- Sorry its iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
    var $body = $(this).contents().find('body');
    $("#content").css({
        height: $body.height(),
        width: $body.width()
    });
})
.attr('src', 'iframeUrlHere');
```

Comment: I added when i am calling resizeIframe function. It is called when i frame is loaded. Can you please look at it now? Your above answer will not work for me as i will have to rewrite everything otherwise.